# How to merge two lists by alternating elements from both lists?

Tags: python, list

I want to merge two lists but in between each other. For example.

```
char = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
num = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
```

I want to have the results as following

```
result = ["A", "1", "B", "2", "C", "3", "D", "4", "E", "5", "F", "6", "G", "7"]
```